# Need help extracting tables from website using Selenium python with date input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

this is my first time using Selenium, I am trying to extract Tables from https://www.fpi.nsdl.co.in/web/Reports/Archive.aspx by using date. I am able to open the calendar in chrome driver but unable to select the desired date. Below is my code, Is there a way to select month/year too? Thanks in advance

```
test_url = "https://www.fpi.nsdl.co.in/web/Reports/Archive.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\prash\Music\fii\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(test_url)
time.sleep(1)
expected_to_date = '17'
driver.find_element_by_id("imgtxtDate").click()
from_day = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[not(contains(@class,'DynarchCalendar-firstcol'))]/a[text()='" + expected_to_date + "']")
from_day.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the calendar provided by the site by using XPath to locate the divs whose attribute is `dyc-date`. Its value seems to correspond to a date.

This views the report for May 10 2022:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

test_url = "https://www.fpi.nsdl.co.in/web/Reports/Archive.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(test_url)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("imgtxtDate").click()
time.sleep(1)

#Go back a previous month
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'DynarchCalendar-prevMonth').click()
time.sleep(1)

#Click on the 5th day
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@dyc-date='20220510']").click()
time.sleep(1)

#Submit
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnSubmit1').click()
```